# How can I scale a webapp with long response time, which currently uses django

Tags: django, multithreading, api, web-applications, mod-wsgi

I am writing a web application with django on the server side. It takes ~4 seconds for server to generate a response to the user. It makes use of a weather api. My application has to make ~50 query to that api for each user request.

Server side uses urllib of python for using the weather api. I used pythons threading to speed up the process because urllib is synchronous. I am using wsgi with apache. The problem is wsgi stack is fully synchronous and when many users use my application, they have to wait for one anothers request to finish. Since each request takes ~4 seconds, this is unacceptable.

I am kind of stuck, what can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Can you precache the data, instead of doing it at request time?

Comment: The data for any point on earth may have to be queried depending on the user. I have to cache the whole worlds weather data and that is way too much. Plus, it changes hourly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mod_wsgi in a multithreaded configuration, or even a multi process configuration, one request should not block another from being able to do something. They should be able to run concurrently. If using a multithreaded configuration, are you sure that you aren't using some locking mechanism on some resource within your own application which precludes requests running through the same section of code? Another possibility is that you have configured Apache MPM and/or mod_wsgi daemon mode poorly so as to preclude concurrent requests.

Anyway, as mentioned in another answer, you are much better off looking at caching strategies to avoid the weather lookups in the first place, or offloading to client.

Comment: I configured wsgi as it is told here: http://bit.ly/EaatF I am using threads for url fetching so I don't think I am locking anything. I haven't done anything special with my apache configuration so maybe that it the problem like you said. I will look at it. Weather lookups are necessary on the server side, I commented about it under that answer.

Comment: Your comment 'I am using threads for url fetching' doesn't make sense. There would be no need for you to create distinct threads to fetch the data unless you are actually firing off multiple back ground threads at the same time to try and parallelise requests and then waiting for them all to finish. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: BTW, you should really look into daemon mode of mod_wsgi. If you only followed those instructions, you would be running in embedded mode, which unless you configure Apache MPM properly, can cause problems Read 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html'.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I am doing. As far as the instructions I followed, (which I figured you wrote :) it also shows using daemon mode. I am using the daemon version. Blog post really helped me understand things btw.

Comment: I figured that locking mechanism was my problem as you said. I fixed it and wsgi is fine now working in daemon mode. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

50 queries to an outside resource per request is probably a bad place to be, and probably not neccesary at all.

The weather doesn't change all that quickly, and so you can probably benefit enormously by just caching results for a while.  Then it doesn't matter how many requests you're getting, you don't need to do more than a few queries per day

If that's not your situation, you might be able to get the client to do the work for you.  Refactor the code so that the weather api aggregation happens on the client in javascript, rather than funneling it all through the server.

Edit: based on comments you've posted, what you are asking for probably cannot be optimized within the constraints of the API you are using.  The problem is that the service is doing a good job of abstracting away the differences in the many sources of weather information they aggregate into a nearest location query.  after all, weather stations provide only point data.

If you talk directly to the technical support people that provide the API, you might find that they are willing to support more complex queries (bounding box), for which they will give you instructions.  More likely, though, they abstract that away because they don't want to actually reveal the resolution that their API actually provides, or because there is some technical reason in the way that they model their data or perform their calculations that would make such queries too difficult to support.

Without that or caching, you are just out of luck.

Comment: 50 queries are done for 50 different locations. The user picks a location on the map and application has to look at the weather of 50 points around that location. It is necessary for an evaluation. The location that user picks can be any point on earth so I'm not sure caching would help. I also thought of using javascript but the api usage policy prevents making my api key public, so that doesn't look like an option.

Comment: Does the API support bounding box queries?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is what I use - http://bit.ly/dlIAIp This api seems to be the only one I could find that can be queried with lat/lon